# No matching record found for external id 'groups_group1' in field 'Group'

Tags: odoo

Please i want to establish access rights for my module, so I modify the file csv I try to install the module, but this error appears at the time of installation of the module:

```
File "/home/omar/odoo/odoo11/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 95, in _load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/home/omar/odoo/odoo11/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 785, in convert_file
    convert_csv_import(cr, module, pathname, fp.read(), idref, mode, noupdate)
  File "/home/omar/odoo/odoo11/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 832, in convert_csv_import
    raise Exception(_('Module loading %s failed: file %s could not be processed:\n %s') % (module, fname, warning_msg))
Exception: Module loading moduletest failed: file moduletest/security/ir.model.access.csv could not be processed:
 No matching record found for external id 'groups_group1' in field 'Group'
No matching record found for external id 'groups_group2' in field 'Group'
```

Comment: Have you written this group(groups_group1,groups_group2) in your XML file?

Comment: yes <button name="send_message" string="Confirm" class="oe_highlight"
                               groups="moduletest_model.group_group1" />

Comment: No I asked whether you have created this group in "res.groups"? but you are talking about assigning this group to Button

Comment: Please share the relevant code (python, xml) for this question. It is really hard to point at a mistake or whatever by knowing like nothing about the base.

Answer (score 4):

One of the things that make this error occur is when you don't respect the order of security files, you have to put your .xml file that is related to security before the .csv file in your __ manifest __.py

Here's a simple example:

```py
    'data': [
        'views/security.xml',
        'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        # ... other includes ...
    ]
```

Comment: Why did you decide so?

Answer (score 0):

**this is a sample code for category and group**

```
 <record model="ir.module.category" id="module_category_stock_quotation_request"> -->
        <!-- <field name="parent_id" ref="module_category_localization" /> -->
        <!-- <field name="name">Stock Transfert Request</field>
        <field name="visible" eval="0" />
    </record> 


 <record id="group_stock_quotation_request_user" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">User</field>
        <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
        <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_stock_quotation_request"/>
    </record>

    <record id="group_stock_quotation_request_manager" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Manager</field>
        <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('transfert_request.group_stock_quotation_request_user'))]"/>
        <field name="category_id" ref="module_category_stock_quotation_request"/>
    </record>
```

Comment: But my case I configure the xml file to create the groups and I can see them in Settings>Uers>group but don't understand why it is not installing properly